# How to retrieve Firebase user "userID" with Facebook authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve Firebase userID. I can retrieve userID when I signedIn with Facebook with "FIRAuthCredential" but can't retrieve it outside it. As, I am creating real-time database therefore I need userID after I signed. Any help is highly appreciated?

```
//In this handler I can retrieve FIR userID using "user.uid"
handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Logged in");

                 FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRFacebookAuthProvider
                                                  credentialWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
                                                  .tokenString];

                 [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                                           completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                               //Retrieved here
                                               [[[ self.databaseRef child:@"users"] child:user.uid]
                                                setValue:@{@"username": userName,
                                                           @"usergender":userGender,
                                                           @"useremail":userEmail,
                                                           @"userfbid":userFBID}];

                                           }];
             }
         }];
```

But outside in another function, it gives error.

```
 void(purchased)
    {
       FIRUser *user;
       NSString *key = [[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] childByAutoId].key;

     //Error here, "user.uid" is empty.
     NSDictionary *subscriptions = @{@"uid": user.uid,
     @"subs_ID": _product.productIdentifier,
     @"StartDate":[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]],
     @"EndDate": [dateFormatter stringFromDate:expirationDate]};

     NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{[@"/User-Subscription/" stringByAppendingString:key]: subscriptions};
     [self.databaseRef updateChildValues:childUpdates];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution.In signIn handler, just save userID in your device and then retrieve it for later use. However, if somebody has another solution, they are more than welcomed.

```
//In this handler I can retrieve FIR userID using "user.uid"
NSUserDefaults *saveID = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Logged in");

                 FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRFacebookAuthProvider
                                                  credentialWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
                                                  .tokenString];

                 [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                                           completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                               //Retrieved here
                                               [[[ self.databaseRef child:@"users"] child:user.uid]
                                                setValue:@{@"username": userName,
                                                           @"usergender":userGender,
                                                           @"useremail":userEmail,
                                                           @"userfbid":userFBID}];

                                           }];

                [saveID setObject:user.uid forKey:k_FIRUserID];
                [saveID synchronize];
             }
         }];
```

//In purchase subscription function

```
void(purchased)
    {
     NSString *key = [[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] childByAutoId].key;
    //Retrieve userID here.
     NSString *saveUserID = [saveapp objectForKey:k_FIRUserID];
     NSDictionary *subscriptions = @{@"uid": saveUserID,
     @"subs_ID": _product.productIdentifier,
     @"StartDate":[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]],
     @"EndDate": [dateFormatter stringFromDate:expirationDate]};

     NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{[@"/User-Subscription/" stringByAppendingString:key]: subscriptions};
     [self.databaseRef updateChildValues:childUpdates];

    }
```